# Regex for not allowing consecutive dots or underscores

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a Regex which allows only alpha numeric characters along with dot (.) and underscore (_)

It does not allow consecutive underscores but it allows consecutive dots. Can anyone please guide me through this problem. I don't want consecutive dots or underscores. 
Below is the JavaScript function

```
function checkLogin() {
  var login = $("#user_login").val();
  var regex = new RegExp("^(?!.*__.*)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$");
  var flag = true;
  if (regex.test(login)) {
    $('#valid_character_error').css("display","none");
  } 
  else  {
    $('#valid_character_error').css("display","block");
    flag = false;
  }
  return flag;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to allow `a._._._.x`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just include the pattern which matches two dots inside the negative lookahead.

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(?!.*(?:__|\\.\\.))[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$");
```

`[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+` would be written as `[\w.]`

**Update:**

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(?!.*?[._]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oV0uI8/1)

Comment: if you don't want to allow `a._._._.x`, then change the negative lookahead to `(?!.*[._]{2})`

Comment: Your solution allows dots. I don't want more than two consecutive dots or two underscores. Also I don't want to allow a._._._.x in my regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj This doesn't work for valid emails like, *avinash.raj@example.com*

Comment: @devGeek what I'm trying to say is, just preceed your email regex with `^(?!.*?[._]{2})` . ie. `^(?!.*?[._]{2})<email_regex_goes_here>$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj how to find fill in the blanks in the paragraph? like I need to find blanks in word document one by one and on next button click next fill in the blank highlighted.

Comment: Blank 1  _____________
Blank 2  _____________
Blank 3  _____________
Variable of string contains “_____”. Find and loop through all blanks in document and create a list. Loop through the list and highlight each blank one-by-one.

Comment: create a single regex for all the blanks like  ` {2,}` Note that I have used blank before `{2,}`  or use this if you want to match tabs as well `( |\t){2,}`

Answer (score 4):

This should do it

```
/^([^._]|[.](?=[^.]|$)|_(?=[^_]|$))*$/
```

Meaning:

- `^(...)*$` the whole string is zero-or-more of...
- `[^._]` a char but not a dot or an underscore
- `|` or
- `[.](?=[^.]|$)` a dot, followed by a different char or by the end of the string (but don't "use" that char)
- `|` or
- `_(?=[^_]|$)` an underscore, followed by a different char or by the end of the string (but don't "use" that char)

In other words you are looking for a sequence of either:

- "regular" chars
- dots not followed by dots
- underscores not followed by underscores

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want `__` or `..` or `._` sequences to appear in your string, then this regex should work:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/;
```

The regex above also reject strings that start or end with `.` or `_`. If you want to allow them:

```
var regex = /^[._]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+([._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*[._]?$/;
```